# Is there any way to terraform a service account access to a specific secret in Google Secret Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-secret-manager

I see there has been some activity to add secret manager support to Terraform here:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/5168

I'm looking for a way to programatically assign secret access to specific Google service accounts. I'm guessing that functionality isn't there yet?

Comment: It's not released yet, but the IAM methods are included: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google-beta/pull/1708/files#diff-8fca81e4ff945e7f28cca9734d1088dd

Answer (score 0):

It's not available now but it seems the feature will be released soon.
I recommend you take a look at the [Google provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and [Google beta  provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google-beta/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) changelogs to be aware of the latest releases.

By the way here you can find the command line tools to [create](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/quickstart#secretmanager-access-secret-version-cli) and [manage](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/managing-secrets#managing-secrets)  secrets.

Answer (score 0):

You can access Secret Manager secrets with Terraform using version 3.8 of the beta provider or higher.

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12"

  required_providers {
    google-beta = ">= 3.8"
  }
}

data "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "my-secret" {
  provider = google-beta

  secret  = "my-secret"
  version = "1"
}
```

Here's how you access the value:

```
output "secret" {
  value = data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.my-secret.secret_data
}
```